# Replace simple RequestMapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, spring-mvc

there's something to replace this in spring mvc ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checklogin")
public String printWelcome() {          
        return "hello";
}
```

Because i have no handling to do, just redirection.

What path we have to put in a href property ?

I try `window.location.href="pages/hello.jsp";` in a javascript code but i got 404 error.
This is my directory stucture:

```
Webcontent
 resources  
    css
 WEB-INF
    pages
      hello.jsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a .jsp page (Or any other resource) under the WEB-INF directory, you can not access it directly from the browser as you are trying to do with the `window.location.href="pages/hello.jsp";`. Put the hello.jsp inside the webcontent directory, but outside of the WEB-INF directory, and you'll not get the 404.

However, if you still want to keep your jsp inside of the WEB-INF directory, you could use a view resolver that prevented you from constructing a controller like the one you show. Take a look at UrlBasedViewResolver, here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s05.html

Comment: it's work now ;) I put the hello.jsp inside the webcontent directory. but i loose my object `<html>
<head><title>Welcome</title></head>
<body>
welcome Mr ${auth.login}
</body>
</html>` i got just `welcome Mr`

Comment: That's because as the request is not processed by the controller, the page doesn't have access to the model.